# Add setValue and getValue to JQueryUI Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

**Goal**: I want to add setValue and getValue functions to JQueryUI Autocomplete widget.

Assuming an autocomplete list has a datasource of id/label pairs, I **want** to call to setValue and getValue like this:

```
// this is how I *want* to call it
$("#tags").autocomplete('setValue', 2);  // should select "two" in the list
$("#tags").autocomplete('getValue')      // if "two" is selected, it should return 2
```

Here's the context HTML:

```
<script>
    // if I pass in 2 for the id, it should select "two"
    function setValueClick(){
       $("#tags").autocomplete('setValue', 2);
    }

    // if "two" is the selected item, getValue should return 2
    function getValueClick(){
        console.log($("#tags").autocomplete('getValue'));
    }
</script>

<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags" /> <br/>

    <button onclick="setValueClick()">Set value to 2</button>
    <button onclick="getValueClick()">Get value</button>
</div>
```

and the JS:

```
$.widget("ui.autocomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    setValue: function(id) {
        // TODO: make this select the item corresponding to the id param
    },
    getValue: function(){
        // TODO: make this return the id of the selected item
    }
});


$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
        {   id: 1,
            label: 'one'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            label: 'two'
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            label: 'three'
        }
    ];

    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});
```

And here's a jsfiddle start:
http://jsfiddle.net/spencerw/55jhx/149/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I changed things up a little bit, but I feel it's for the better. Feel free to use this in any way you see fit.

You'll notice I added more attributes to the buttons (`ele` to both and `value` to the setter). The `ele` property should be set to the ID of the `<input>` element you want to modify/retrieve results from. The `value` property (in the setter) should be set to the id attribute of the `availableTags` object that you want to show the label of (not the index of the object within the `availableTags` array). I took out the `onclick` attributes, and am handling that in the JS, so I could remove the `<script>` tags from the HTML pane (this is more just to make it a little easier to read in jsFiddle).

Here's the modified HTML:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags" /> <br/>

    <button class='setValueClick' value='2' ele='tags'>Set value to 2</button>
    <button class='getValueClick' ele='tags'>Get value</button>
</div>
```

And the modified JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.setValueClick', function(){
    var ele = $('#' + $(this).attr('ele'));
    ele.autocomplete('setValue', $(this).attr('value'));
});
$(document).on('click', 'button.getValueClick', function(){
    var ele = $('#' + $(this).attr('ele'));
    alert(ele.autocomplete('getValue'));
});

$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
        { id: 1, label: 'one' },
        { id: 2, label: 'two' },
        { id: 3, label: 'three' }
    ];

    $.widget("ui.autocomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
        setValue: function(id) {
            var input = $(this.element[0]);
            $.each(availableTags, function(k, v){
                if(v.id == id){
                    input.val(v.label);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        },
        getValue: function(){
            var val = $(this.element[0]).val(), ret = false;
            $.each(availableTags, function(k, v){
                if(v.label == val){
                    ret = v.id;
                    return false;
                }
            });
            return ret;
        }
    });

    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});
```

You can see a working, super-documented, version of the answer here:
http://jsfiddle.net/hftn7oqw/

Comment: thanks, this is great!  The only change I might make is to access the data from the source method, since I might, for example, populate from a function, like so:  `var tags = $(this.element[0]).autocomplete( "option", "source" );` and use that in the `$.each(tags, ...)`.  I made that change and a few other minor ones here:    http://jsfiddle.net/spencerw/Lcw8r6yk/

Comment: [ran out of time editing the first comment] @mark.hch thanks, this is great!  Since I might populate the list from a function, for example, the only change I might make is to access the data from the source option, like so:  `var tags = $(this.element[0]).autocomplete( "option", "source" );` and use that in the foreach: `$.each(tags, ...)`.  I made that change and a few other minor ones here:    http://jsfiddle.net/spencerw/Lcw8r6yk/